# How to assign image values to a Triclops structure from matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

I have the following c++ typedef struct that I work with:

```
typedef struct TriclopsColorImage
{
 // The number of rows in the image.
 int             nrows;
 // The number of columns in the image.
 int             ncols;
 // The row increment of the image.
 int             rowinc;
 // The pixel data for red band of the image.
    unsigned char*    red;
 // The pixel data for green band of the image.
    unsigned char*    green;
 // The pixel data for blue band of the image.
    unsigned char*    blue;

} TriclopsColorImage;
```

I have an image which gets passed to a `mex` function as `prhs[1]`
How do I correctly assign the fields of red, green and blue. Here I have

```
TriclopsColorImage colorImage;
```

And I am doing something like this:

```
    colorImage.nrows=(int) mxGetN(prhs[1]);
    colorImage.ncols=(int) mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    colorImage.rowinc=colorImage.ncols*2;
    colorImage.red=?
    colorImage.green=?
    colorImage.blue=?
```

Comment: what is "row increment"?

Comment: Rowinc indicates the number of bytes between the beginning of a row and the beginning of the following row, according to the description from triclops library

Comment: in the previous example each pixel was using 16 bits or 2 bytes per columnwise element, but know in your answer, since the source is unit8, the number of bytes for each line is colorImage.ncols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the image to your mex function as a `uint8` type of size `m`-by-`n`-by-3.
For example:

```
img = imread( 'football.jpg' ); 
myMeFunction( someArg, img ); % note that prhs[1] is the SECOND argument
```

Now inside your mex:

```
colorImage.nrows=(int) mxGetM(prhs[1]); // M is number of rows!
colorImage.ncols=(int) mxGetN(prhs[1]) / 3; // assuming third dimension is three.
// for the colors:
unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)mxGetData(prhs[1]);    
colorImage.red = p;
colorImage.green = p + colorImage.nrows*colorImage.ncols;
colorImage.blue = p + 2*colorImage.nrows*colorImage.ncols;
```

Please read **carefully** the description of [mxGetN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetn.html).